# C, Why printf must put inside the loop, rather than outside?

Tags: c

**Why printf should put inside the loop?**

```
  int x;
  int y;

  for (x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
printf ("%d\n", x); // if i put inside the loop, output = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

}

printf ("%d\n\n", x); // if i put in outside, output = 11


}
```

Comment: printf can be **everywhere** you want it to be ;) You may need to read the basics of coding again :) specially loops

Comment: You might want to pick up a book on C, guessing at behaviour/ making assumptions are not good ways to learn C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why printf should put inside the loop?

It does not have to be put inside a for-loop, it can be placed anywhere.

Here, the author of this code is trying to explain the difference between putting the printf() statement inside the for-loop vs outside the for-loop.

When it is inside the for-loop, it is run everytime the loop runs, printing the incremented value of x from the last iteration. Since x is declared outside of the loop, the value of x is saved after the last iteration, and is printed in the printf() statement outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for understanding my Question,  i just want to know the difference between puting printf inside and outside, sorry for my broken english T-T

Answer (score 0):

It's because that's how loops work. In your look you're asking to print and then increase i 10 times. Then after the 10th iteration is finished it will increment i one more time, hence that's why it will be equal to 11 after the last printf.

Comment: very Thanks Man !!!!

Comment: the 11 is actually come from the x++ right ?  because 10 meet the condition ,then x++

Comment: That is correct, whenever you use (x)++ the program uses the x variable THEN increments it. If you use the ++(x) the program first increments then uses the variable.